# What is the process behind finding a Cayley permutation representation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

For example, let's find the Cayley permutation representation of $\mathcal D_3$ in $S_6$.

$\mathcal D_3 = \left<r,s \mid r^3=s^2=1, rs=sr^{-1}\right>$.

Write,

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
1 & r & r^2 & s & rs & r^2s
\end{pmatrix}

By multiplying on the right, we find:

$\varphi_1=()$

$\varphi_r=(123)(456)$

$\varphi_{r^2}=(132)(465)$

$\varphi_s=(14)(26)(35)$

$\varphi_{rs}=(15)(24)(36)$

$\varphi_{r^2s}=(16)(25)(34)$

> What is the formal process behind finding a Cayley permutation representation. Is this a group action from $\mathcal D_3$ on $\mathbb Z_6$? A group action wouldn't give you cycles like this.

Comment: This is a group action on a set. In your example, the set is the elements of the group itself. In general, permutation representations come from the group action on cosets of a given subgroup.

Comment: So, this is $\mathcal D_3 \times \mathcal D_3 \to \text{Sym}(\mathcal D_3)$?

Answer (score 3):

This all looks good to me. You were looking for an injective homomorphism $\phi : \mathcal{D}_3 \to \operatorname{Sym}(\mathcal{D}_3) \cong S_6$ by letting $\mathcal{D}_3$ act on itself; and that's exactly what you've found.

In general, you've followed the process:

- Set up a bijection, $L : \{1, 2, \ldots, \lvert G\rvert \} \to G$, labeling the elements of your group
- For each group element $g \in G$, construct the permutation $\varphi_g = L^{-1} \circ r_g \circ L,$ which is a permutation in $S_{\lvert G \rvert}$ (here, the map $r_g : G \times G \to G$ is the *right multiplication by $g$* map; I don't know if you used right- or left-multiplication, but it would  only be a superficial difference leading to isomorphic representations)
- Your injective homomorphism is then $\phi : G \to S_{\lvert G \lvert}$, given by $\phi(g) = \varphi_g$

I'm not sure I understand your comments about cycles, or $\Bbb Z_6$. You're just writing permutations in $S_6$ in cycle notation; of course there will be cycles. It doesn't mean that your group is cyclic (but again, I'm really not sure what that comment means).

As far as "a group action on $\Bbb Z_6$", I guess you could call it that, but it would be misleading. You could consider this a group action on **any** set of $6$ elements (by setting up a bijection like the $L$ used here), but traditionally you'll pick the integers from $1$ to the order of your group (or just the original group elements themselves). However, just because your group acts on a set in bijection with $\Bbb Z_6$, that doesn't mean this permutation representation ties them together in *any* way. It's strictly about cardinality here; groups *act* on sets, you need a homomorphism to $\Bbb Z_6$ (which this isn't) if you want to relate their algebraic properties.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the formal process behind finding a Cayley permutation representation.

For any group $G$ of order $n\in\mathbb N$, I think that the key point of the "formal process" is the red-typed isomorphism:
$$G\stackrel{Cayley}{\hookrightarrow}S_G\color{red}{\cong}S_n$$
That isomorphism is non-canonical, as it is explicitly given by:
$$l_a\mapsto(i\mapsto f^{-1}(l_a(f(i)))) \tag1$$
where $l_a$ is the left multiplication by $a\in G$, and $f\colon\{1,\dots, n\}\to G$ is *any* bijection.

In your case, $D_3=\{e,r,r^2,s,rs,r^2s\}$. Now, for $f$ let's (arbitrarily!) take:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&1\mapsto e \\
&2\mapsto r \\
&3\mapsto r^2 \\
&4\mapsto s \\
&5\mapsto rs \\
&6\mapsto r^2s \\
\tag2
\end{alignat}
Within this (arbitrary!) choice for $f$, what is the permutation representation of, say, the element $r^2s$? Let's put the recipe $(1)$+$(2)$ into operation:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&f^{-1}(l_{r^2s}(f(\color{cyan}{1})))=f^{-1}(r^2se)=f^{-1}(r^2s)=\color{cyan}{6}\\
&f^{-1}(l_{r^2s}(f(\color{magenta}{2})))=f^{-1}(r^2sr)=f^{-1}(rs)=\color{magenta}{5}\\
&f^{-1}(l_{r^2s}(f(\color{green}{3})))=f^{-1}(r^2sr^2)=f^{-1}(s)=\color{green}{4}\\
&f^{-1}(l_{r^2s}(f(\color{green}{4})))=f^{-1}(r^2ss)=f^{-1}(r^2)=\color{green}{3}\\
&f^{-1}(l_{r^2s}(f(\color{magenta}{5})))=f^{-1}(r^2srs)=f^{-1}(r)=\color{magenta}{2}\\
&f^{-1}(l_{r^2s}(f(\color{cyan}{6})))=f^{-1}(r^2sr^2s)=f^{-1}(e)=\color{cyan}{1}\\
\end{alignat}
That is how your "$\varphi_{r^2s}=(\color{cyan}{16})(\color{magenta}{25})(\color{green}{34})$" pops formally up! (And likewise for the permutation representation of the other elements of $D_3$, still in the arbitrary setting $(2)$.)